# Why the last line of text is partially cut off / not visible?

Tags: html, css

you can go here: http://phpbb32.majordroid.com/index.php

and see live example

you can see this:

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL4VJ.jpg)

letter "g" is partially visible... and all other similar letters like q, j, p, etc... have the same problem...

how to fix this problem to see the last line normal ?

Also from admin panel I can change font family, and then for some font family the last line of text is normal visible, but for some is not like in this case.

is It possible to adjust to be normally visible for all font family types ?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like your css for `dl.row-item dt .list-inner, dl dt .list-inner, dt.draft-title .list-inner, dt.draft-title-control-panel .list-inner` has a `max-height` that is slightly to short, making the `overflow` cut off the text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compromise and choose which way you want to go, max-fixed height might not always work. If you're title have max characters then you don't really need that `max-height`

So remove those from your `list-inner`:

```
overflow: hidden; 
max-height: 3.6em;
```

And hide the `forum-description`?

Comment: Hi, this works partially, you can now see on live example. for some font family works, but for some as you can see it starts a new line.

Comment: @senf as `Will Thresher` said this is due to the max-height, do you want a fixed max-height? you have to compromise something there

Answer (score 0):

Because `.list-inner` has css property `overflow: hidden` set, and a `max-height` as well it is cutting off the text. If you remove both of this properties it will display correctly.